# sed not replacing HTML tags

Tags: html, sed

Hi I am trying to replace a tag with another; putting the replace string and string that needs to be inserted as below:

```
ReplaceString='\<link rel=\"stylesheet"\ type=\"text\/css"\ title=\"Style"\ href=\"..\/stylesheet\.css">'

InsertStyle='\<Style>body { font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica; color:#000000; } table tr td, table tr th { font-size: 68%; } table\.details tr th{ font-weight: bold; text-align:left; background:#a6caf0; } table\.details tr td{ background:#eeeee0; }  p { line-height:1\.5em; margin-top:0\.5em; margin-bottom:1\.0em; } h1 { margin: 0px 0px 5px; font: 165% verdana,arial,helvetica } h2 { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0\.5em; font: bold 125% verdana,arial,helvetica } h3 { margin-bottom: 0\.5em; font: bold 115% verdana,arial,helvetica } h4 { margin-bottom: 0\.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h5 { margin-bottom: 0\.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h6 { margin-bottom: 0\.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } \.Error { font-weight:bold; color:red; } \.Failure { font-weight:bold; color:purple; } \.Properties { text-align:right; }<\/Style>'
```

**using command:**

```
sed -i 's/$ReplaceString/$InsertStyle/g' /tmp/test.html
```

more /tmp/test.html

```
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Unit Test Results: B2B_PIV_PROD.Run_PIV</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="../stylesheet.css">

</html>
```

not working; seems like the $ReplaceString is not understood by sed.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion; can you suggest something else i am using bash to update this html file.

Comment: If you want `sed` to see the contents of `$ReplaceString`, don't use single quotes. Use double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is the wrong tool for this since it cannot operator on strings and is a nightmare to try to get to behave as if it were operating on strings, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001). Also you can't just stick a backslash in front of every character that you think might be a regexp metacharacter since when you get it wrong you can be turning that char INTO a metacharacter (e.g. `<` is a literal char but when you wrote `\<` you turned it into a word-boundary metachar).

If you want to replace a string with another string, just use a tool that can operate on strings, e.g. awk.

Assuming that all the backslashes in your variables were because you were trying to make sed behave as if it understood strings, remove them and then it's simply:

```
ReplaceString='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="../stylesheet.css">'

InsertStyle='<Style>body { font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica; color:#000000; } table tr td, table tr th { font-size: 68%; } table.details tr th{ font-weight: bold; text-align:left; background:#a6caf0; } table.details tr td{ background:#eeeee0; }  p { line-height:1.5em; margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:1.0em; } h1 { margin: 0px 0px 5px; font: 165% verdana,arial,helvetica } h2 { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 125% verdana,arial,helvetica } h3 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 115% verdana,arial,helvetica } h4 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h5 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h6 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } .Error { font-weight:bold; color:red; } .Failure { font-weight:bold; color:purple; } .Properties { text-align:right; }</Style>'

awk -v old="$ReplaceString" -v new="$InsertStyle" '
    beg = index($0,old) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,beg-1) new substr($0,beg+length(old))
    }
    { print }
' file
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Unit Test Results: B2B_PIV_PROD.Run_PIV</title>
<Style>body { font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica; color:#000000; } table tr td, table tr th { font-size: 68%; } table.details tr th{ font-weight: bold; text-align:left; background:#a6caf0; } table.details tr td{ background:#eeeee0; }  p { line-height:1.5em; margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:1.0em; } h1 { margin: 0px 0px 5px; font: 165% verdana,arial,helvetica } h2 { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 125% verdana,arial,helvetica } h3 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 115% verdana,arial,helvetica } h4 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h5 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } h6 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; font: bold 100% verdana,arial,helvetica } .Error { font-weight:bold; color:red; } .Failure { font-weight:bold; color:purple; } .Properties { text-align:right; }</Style>

</html>
```

Comment: the awk seems to be more reliable; & it worked; can you explain that a bit as well.
Also how will it save these changes to the file since i can see the file is not modified.

Comment: `index()` finds the string in the file and returns the index of where that string begins in the line. `substr()` creates substrings of the line with the specific start point and number of chars. Then the `$0 =` assignment just pieces the line back together with the part before the old string, then the new string, then the part after the old string. With any UNIX command you can do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` to change the original file. If you have GNU awk you can use `awk -i inplace ....` to do it.